# What's the meaning of the phrase, " He/she/somebody would get you."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Whenever I stayed (would it grammatically correct if I used **would stay** here, instead of **stayed**?) up late, past my curfew, my dad would come to my bedroom, and tell me if I didn't go to bed quick, **the boogeyman would get me.**

What's the meaning of the **the boogeyman would get me** part?
Is it grammatically correct, or should it be some other phrase used there instead of what was used there?

Comment: See [here, 22nd meaning](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get).

Comment: Regarding “stayed” vs. “would stay”, why do *you* want to change it? Do you think it's missing something, that the meaning isn't clear? Anyhow, I would use the former.

Comment: As a minor twist, in American English, I'd say *get to bed* rather than *go to bed*. This is independent of the use of *get* later in the sentence. It just sounds better, more idiomatic.

Comment: @user2684291, i just wanted to know whether the two are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: many people would say "If I would stay", but I think that is still not regarded as standard English (I wouldn't say it myself).

For the second part, yes "The bogeyman would get me" is fine - it is the past (for reported speech) of "The bogeyman will get me", that is, will catch me.